# BMW E90 Remapping/Tune for Stop/Start and DPF slowly undone?

Tags: bmw, diesel-particulate-filter, 320d, e90

Ever since I bought my 2011 E90 320D the stop start function never seemed to work. I wasn't too bothered by this and just assumed it had been coded out.

After about a year, the stop start would randomly would kick in with more and more frequency.
Then suddenly today an error appears for the stop start function and 20 minutes later a DPF error appears (CC-ID 49).
The stop start error has gone but not the DPF which is extra surprising as I have done a lot of long distance driving just a month ago.

Is it possible the DPF was mapped/coded out after being physically hollowed and that had come up suddenly, or is it just a coincidence?

The car had only just passed the yearly inspection too here in Ireland (NCT) 2 days prior to this and that includes an emissions test.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there a specific code for the DPF?